# Axios in node.js check url before executing code

Tags: node.js, axios

I dont find anything that works for me so I ask here:

I am trying to get some data from a website with axios. It works great, but if I input the wrong URL I get an error. I want to check if the URL with its complete path to the page I desire exists.

I tried npm package url-exists but it just said the path didn't exist eventho it did.

Is there a simple way to check if a path like for example "https://github.com/enterprise" exists or if it doesn't?

Comment: `Is there a simple way to check if a path like for example "https://github.com/enterprise" exists or if it doesn't?` Yes, request it. If it 404s it it probably doesn't exist.

Comment: Addition to @tkausl's comment, if you get a 3xx response to a different domain, you might be in trouble, and any 4xx code indicates a request problem. If your HTTP response code is in the 200 range (and particularly 200, 201, 202, or 204) you should be good. All `url-exists` does is check if the status code is in the 400 range, but it's also very outdated and unnecessary — you can check the status code yourself in your Axios call, it's in [`response.status`](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema).

Comment: Thank you guys response.status and checkig for 400 codes worked well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a request anyway to check if the url exists. So you can handle it when you got 404 status code in `catch` error block of `axios` function.

Answer (score 2):

The only way is making the request, you can handle this scenario using a try/catch block

```js
const getSomething = async () => {
  try {
    const something = await axios.get("www.website.fake")
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I already used the catch error function in axios that was recommended in the comments and it worked well.